# intento comparar el resultado de una funcion de tipo int y un numero error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++, codeblocks

> **intento hacer una comparacion entre el valor retornado de una funcion y un numero **

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <conio.h>
 using namespace std;
 // no se si con voltajes es int o float
 int promvolt (int v1,int v2, int v3)
 {
 return((v1 + v2 +v3)/3);
 }


 int main()
 {   int volt1=0, volt2=0,volt3=0;
 cout << "---VOLTAJES---" << endl;
 cout << "introduzca el primer voltaje" << endl;
 cin >> volt1;
 cout << "introduzca el segundo voltaje" << endl;
 cin >> volt2;
 cout << "introduzca el tercer voltaje" << endl;
 cin >> volt3;

 cout << "El voltaje promedio es: "<< promvolt(volt1,volt2,volt3)<<endl;
  
 intento de comparacion
```

> **intento comparar `if (promvolt <= 115 )` y me sale error**

```
 if (promvolt <= 115 )
     cout << "VOLTAJE CORRECTO" << endl;
 else if ( promvolt > 115 && promvolt <= 220)
       cout << "ALTO VOLTAJE" << endl;


    else
        cout<<"PELIGRO"<< endl;

  
 getch();
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que `promvolt` es el nombre de la función, no una variable. Lo que tendrías que hacer es almacenar en una variable el resultado de la función `promvolt` para usarlo posteriormente:

```
...

// Almacena el resultado
int promedio = promvolt(volt1,volt2,volt3);
cout << "El voltaje promedio es: "<< promedio <<endl;

...

// Puedes usar el resultado para realizar comparaciones
if (promedio <= 115 )
     cout << "VOLTAJE CORRECTO" << endl;
 else if ( promedio > 115 && promedio <= 220)
       cout << "ALTO VOLTAJE" << endl;


    else
        cout<<"PELIGRO"<< endl;

  
 getch();
 return 0;
}
```